# how to stream video from FTP in PHP

Tags: php, ftp, stream

is there any way, how to play movie or get some file (ex. jpg, pdf) from distance FTP server?
I've got an app on my PHP server and really lot of bigsized files, so I store it on FTP. I need to play (videos are the biggest problem) these videos via that app... 
I've found ftp_get() function, but it seems to work like - "copy this file to my php server and than play",... it's not acceptable for long time.
Any ideas/solutions?
PS: excuse me my english and maybe not so detailed description.

Comment: maybe you could try `curl` - it can connect via `ftp`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [stream audio file from FTP server to Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361609/stream-audio-file-from-ftp-server-to-android-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP is a file transfer protocol so it's not the right tool.

Few ways to do it:

1. [PHP HTML5 Video Streaming Tutorial](http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial) ([`PHP stream`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php))
2. [Pseudo Streaming MP4’s with PHP](http://www.tuxxin.com/php-mp4-streaming/)
3. [Streaming a large file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914912/streaming-a-large-file-using-php)

Comment: First option looks really great and easy to use, but,... is it possible to use like a path to that file "ftp://..."?

Comment: @RadimKleinpeter if you can always make your url like this `ftp://username:password@127.0.10.1/dir/video.mp4`